# javascript constructor referencing this is not updating property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I apologize for the confusing question naming, I'm particularly new to constructors in javascript and not too sure how to phrase it, but here's the issue I am struggling with.

I'm using a Builder concept (constructor here) to create an object and set particular values to it, which looks like this:

**DataBuilder.js**

```
export class DataBuilder {
    static getDefaultData() {
        return new DataBuilder();
    }

    constructor() {
        this.test = 'original';
        this.data = {
            title: `myTitle`,
            meta: [
                    {
                    hid: "og:title",
                    name: "og:title",
                    property: "og:title",
                    content: `Would like some content here with ${this.test} in the middle of a string`,
                    },
               ]
         }
    }

    setTestData(input) {
        this.test = input;
        return this;
    }

    build() {
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

And I call it from my vue component

**index.vue**

```
export default {
  head() {
    return DataBuilder.getDefaultData()
      .setTestData("testing123")
      .build();
  },
}
```

On building the object, it shows that `this.test` is successfully updated with `testing123`. However, the `content` inside the `meta` doesn't update, and still shows `content: original`. Ideally, the `meta`/`content` part should have updated to show `content: testing123`.

I have this idea that the `this` variable is not "reactive" or updating inside the constructor, so I'm wondering whats the correct way to approach this. Where do I need to update all the fields with a particular `set` function?

Comment: String are assigned by value, not by reference in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to move the `data` setting into `build()` so that it always sets `data` with the most up-to-date field values:

```js
export class DataBuilder {
    //...

    build() {
        this.data = {
            title: `myTitle`,
            meta: [
                {
                    hid: 'og:title',
                    name: 'og:title',
                    property: 'og:title',
                    content: `Would like some content here with ${this.test} in the middle of a string`,
                },
            ]
        };
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

```js
class DataBuilder {
    static getDefaultData() {
        return new DataBuilder();
    }

    constructor() {
        this.test = 'original';
    }

    setTestData(input) {
        this.test = input;
        return this;
    }

    build() {
        this.data = {
            title: `myTitle`,
            meta: [
                {
                    hid: 'og:title',
                    name: 'og:title',
                    property: 'og:title',
                    content: `Would like some content here with ${this.test} in the middle of a string`,
                },
            ]
        };
        return this.data;
    }
}

const data = DataBuilder.getDefaultData().setTestData('foo').setTestData('bar').build()
console.log(data)
```

Comment: It's not the only way, but it's the most appropriate way using the `Builder` pattern. Making it reactive is possible, but overkill with this pattern. Why do you want reactivity here?

Comment: just a curious question, but understood :)

Answer (score 1):

```
content: `Would like some content here with ${this.test}`
```

is evaluated on assignment **only**, not on accessing/reading it.

If you need that, you need to define the property as an accessor property with a getter:

```
this.data = {
        title: "myTitle",
        meta: [
                {
                    hid: "og:title",
                    name: "og:title",
                    property: "og:title",
                },
           ]
     }
this.data.meta.forEach(obj => 
    Object.defineProperty(
        obj, 
        "content", 
        { 
            get: function() { 
                return `Would like some content here with ${this.test} in the middle of a string` 
            }, 
            enumerable: true 
        }
    )
);
```